# SOAP request to download log data from the RFID attendance machine to a web service using PHP

Tags: xml, laravel, soap, xmlhttprequest, rfid

I want to create a SOAP XML request for a 2014 model attendance machine that reads RFID cards. I received a SOAP manual that instructed me to **install SOAP SDK 3.0,** which I have done. I proceeded to the next step, which is to download attendance log data from the machine. The attendance machine is a Solution brand, similar to the Solutions C1 model. I couldn't find an exact photo of the machine on the internet, but the closest match I found was the C1 model. Here is a photo of the attendance machine[image]

Here is the description of the C1 machine:

Access Control (AC): 1 Relay Output 2A 12V
AC Facilities: 50 Time Zones, 5 Grouping, 10 Combination.
Standalone, does not require a computer
User Capacity: 30,000 RFID Cards
Transaction Log Capacity: 50,000 transactions
**PC Communication: TCP/IP (RJ45), RS232/485, USB Port**
Response Time: <= 1 second
Matching Types: 1:1 and 1:N
Standard Features: USB Flash Disk, Alarm Function, Door Controller, SMS Message, etc.
Weigend Port: for connecting additional RFID Readers.
LCD and Speaker for signal identification.

Based on the information I received from the staff, the attendance machine is connected to a PC with attendance management software using a LAN cable. The IP address is **192.168.**.**** and the **port is 4370**. Here is an example of SOAP XML request and response for downloading attendance data:
4.1.3.1 Get all information log

```
Read out the attendance record from attendance machines. 
[XML protocols] 
**Request Xml:**
<GetAttLog>
<ArgComKey xsi:type="xsd:integer”>ComKey</ArgComKey>
<Arg>
<PIN xsi:type="xsd:integer”>Job Number</PIN>
</Arg>
</GetAttLog>

**Response Xml:**
<GetAttLogResponse>
  <Row>
    <PIN>XXXXX</PIN>
    <DateTime >YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS</DateTime>
    <Verified>X</Verified>
    <Status>X</Status>
    <WorkCode>XXXXX</WorkCode>
  </Row>
</GetAttLogResponse>

**[Parameters]** 
ComKey: communications Password 
PIN: User ID (Registration). 

**[Return value]** 

If successful, return log information, or return Null. 
Pin: User ID (Registration). 
DateTime: Date Time. 
Verified: Authentication method. 
Status: Attendance status. 
WorkCode: work code
```

Here is an example of PHP script for downloading attendance log data:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contoh Koneksi Mesin Absensi Menggunakan SOAP Web Service</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#caffcb">
    <h3>Download Log Data</h3>

    <?php
      $IP = "192.168.**.**";
      $Key= "0";
      if($IP == "") $IP= "192.168.**.**";
      if($Key == "") $Key="0";
    ?>

    <form action="tarikdata.php" method="GET">
        IP Address: <input type="text" name="ip" value="<?php echo $IP; ?>" size="15"><br>
        Comm Key: <input type="text" name="key" size="5" value="<?= $Key; ?>"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Download">
    </form>

    <br>

    <?php if (isset($_GET["ip"])) {?>
       <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1">
          <tr align="center">
             <td><b>UserID</b></td>
             <td width="200"><b>Tanggal & Jam</b></td>
             <td><b>Verifikasi</b></td>
             <td><b>Status</b></td>
          </tr>

          <?php
             $Connect = fsockopen($IP,$port, $errno, $errstr, 1);
             //$Connect = stream_socket_client("tcp://$IP:$port", $errno, $errstr, 1);

             if ($Connect) {
                 $soap_request = "<GetAttLog><ArgComKey xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">" . $Key . " 
                                  </ArgComKey><Arg><PIN xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">All</PIN></Arg></GetAttLog>";
                 $newLine = "\r\n";
                 fputs($Connect, "POST /iWsService HTTP/1.0" . $newLine);
                 fputs($Connect, "Content-Type: text/xml" . $newLine);
                 fputs($Connect, "Content-Length: " . strlen($soap_request) . $newLine . $newLine);
                 fputs($Connect, $soap_request . $newLine);
                 
                 $buffer = "";
                 while ($Response = fgets($Connect, 1024)) {
                     $buffer = $buffer . $Response;
                 }
             } else {
                 echo "Koneksi Gagal";
             }

             include("parse.php");
             $buffer = Parse_Data($buffer, "<GetAttLogResponse>", "</GetAttLogResponse>");
             $buffer = explode("\r\n", $buffer);

             for ($a = 0; $a < count($buffer); $a++) {
                 $data = Parse_Data($buffer[$a], "<Row>", "</Row>");
                 $PIN = Parse_Data($data, "<PIN>", "</PIN>");
                 $DateTime = Parse_Data($data, "<DateTime>", "</DateTime>");
                 $Verified = Parse_Data($data, "<Verified>", "</Verified>");
                 $Status = Parse_Data($data, "<Status>", "</Status>");
          ?>
              <tr align="center">
                 <td><?php $PIN ?></td>
                 <td><?php $DateTime ?></td>
                 <td><?php $Verified ?></td>
                 <td><?php $Status ?></td>
              </tr>
        <?php } ?>
     </table>
   <?php }?>
</body>
```

this error:

```
**Warning: fsockopen(): Unable to connect to 192.168.**.**:4370 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) in C:\laragon\www\soapabsensi\tarikdata.php on line 37
  Connection Failed.**
```

And this is the code on line 37:

```
$Connect = fsockopen($IP,$port, $errno, $errstr, 1);
```

When I tried it on the attendance machine at my location with the X606-s model, it successfully connected to the machine's IP. However, when I tried it on my client's IP, it failed repeatedly. What should I do? I'm confused. Help me

Comment: What status code are you getting when you fail?  If you are not getting any response it means you are using the wrong IP, there is no route to the IP address, or TLS is failing do to a certificate.  I would start by trying PING to verify the IP and Route.

Comment: this status code:Warning: fsockopen(): Unable to connect to 192.168.**.**:4370 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) in C:\laragon\www\soapabsensi\tarikdata.php on line 37
Connection failed.                                                                                                         
 And this is the code on line 37:
$Connect = fsockopen($IP,$port, $errno, $errstr, 1);

Comment: I couldn't have entered the IP address incorrectly because I obtained the IP directly from them.

Comment: Did you try ping?  The error could be either hardware of software.  The ethernet connection could be broken on the device.  It is an old device so I do not think it is using HTTPS.  You need to get PING working first.

Comment: @jdweng I have tried PING that IP from a PC directly connected to the attendance machine, and the PING was successful.

Comment: Turn off the machine and try PING again just incase there is more than one machine with the IP address.  PING should fail.  If PING still works than you have more than one machine with same IP.  It is also possible another application is using the same port number.  You can get the active port number from cmd.exe >Netstat -A.   The port number could also be blocked by a anti virus or firewall.  You can also try connecting with PUTTY as a Telnet connection.

Comment: In the office, there is only one attendance machine with the specific IP address and port. When using the "Netstat -A" command, it will display all active connections and listening ports on the local machine. It will not directly point to the IP address of the attendance machine ?

Comment: Is port 4370 showing in the Netstat Results?

Comment: I have tried using "netstat" in the Command Prompt, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Open cmd.exe and type > Netstat -a